# How to put one div onto another with transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create something such that, depending on the state, a given div appears overlapping another div from the right side, here is my code:

```
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [hasConfirmedAccount, setHasConfirmedAccount] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <div style={{ float: "left", width: "50%" }}>
          <div
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "#fafafafa" }}
          ></div>
        </div>

        <div id='notLoggedIn' style={{ float: "right", width: "50%" }}>
          {!loggedIn && (
            <div>
                WHEN LOGGED IN === TRUE
            </div>
          )}

          <div
            style={
              loggedIn && !hasConfirmedAccount 
                ? { width: "100%", transition: "ease-in-out 5s" }
                : { display: "none" }
            }
          >
            <div id="notConfirmedAccount">WHENE LOGGED IN === TRUE AND hasConfirmedAccount === FALSE</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

The code works fine, when `loggedIn === true` and `hasConfirmedAccount === false` div with `id = notConfirmedAccount` has been displayed instead of div with `id=notLoggedIn`, but displaying this div does not work flowing, I want a slow leaving effect of the div on the right side that would overlap the previous div

can someone tell me what to do this?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

1. install animate.css => $ npm install animate.css --save
   [animate.css](https://animate.style/#documentation)

2.import "./animate.css" at top your component or project

3.just put the name of aniamte on className like this pattern in your div

```
<div className={style.forgot} className='animate__animated animate__fadeInDown'>
```

also you should control your showing div with state

Answer (score 0):

Use React animation Add-Ons `ReactTransitionGroup` and `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`

The ReactTransitionGroup add-on component is a low-level API for animation, and ReactCSSTransitionGroup is an add-on component for easily implementing basic CSS animations and transitions.

https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html